# Set relative java-classpath for subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I have 2 installations: One on my laptop and a SLURM installation. I would like to set relative paths in my python functions, so I just can pull via git and run it.

The problem: My jar files are in
`/Users/me/libs/jena/lib/*` or `~/libs/jena/lib/*` on my laptop and in `/home/user/me/libs/jena/lib/*` or `~/libs/jena/lib/*` on the server.

I'm aware of and tried `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'../../libs/jena/lib/*')`, also directly setting `~/path/` doesn't work.

What puzzles me is running a shebang script with a `os.path.join` works fine, but setting a classpath like:

```
cmd = ["java", "-cp", os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'../../libs/jena/lib/*')"+":.", java_file, args]
proc = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

doesn't work.

Thanks for your help

Comment: `Popen` accepts an `env` argument, which is a dict containing environment variables. You can copy the `os.environ` (current environment) and add the `CLASSPATH` in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can try removing the `*` in your path; it should be simply `../../libs/jena/lib/`

Second, you could set the `CLASSPATH` variable to the correct value in both your `.bash_profile` files on the laptop and on the cluster.

```
export CLASSPATH=~/libs/jena/lib/
```

This will work because Bash will substitute `~` with your home when the `.bash_profile` file is sourced (upon login.) This does not work within a Python script because Bash is then not involved (Only Bash understands `~` as the user's home directory.)

Using the environment variable would also allow you to have distinct library paths on the laptop and on the cluster. For instance if you wanted to try a newer version of one of the libraries.

Comment: I can't remove the * in the path - it needs to match every jar in the directory - but the rest worked with alexpeits comment above (using os.environ)